# How to put URL/$directory into rewrite url parameter in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-config, nginx-location

What I need is to pass as a parameter what comes after the slash.

https://example.com/berlin
to
https://example.com/index.php?c=berlin

So far for testing I had done it like this:

```
location / berlin {
         return 301 https://example.com/index.php?c=berlin;
}
```

The problem is that the "berlin" is a variable, each user will put a different city.

Comment: You could use `rewrite ^/([^/]+)$  https://example.com/index.php?c=$1? permanent;`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot! @RichardSmith